# Data validation Script loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, processing-efficiency

I have a code to create a data validation on a cell from a range next to it.

**example:**

```
var cellC4 = cell.getRange('F11');
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('MAIN!AG11:AG11');
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
cellC4.setDataValidation(rule);

var cellC5 = cell.getRange('F12');
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('MAIN!AG12:AG12');
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
cellC5.setDataValidation(rule);

var cellC6 = cell.getRange('F13');
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('MAIN!AG13:AG13');
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
cellC6.setDataValidation(rule);

var cellC7 = cell.getRange('F14');
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('MAIN!AG14:AG14');
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
cellC7.setDataValidation(rule);
```

can someone help me do it correctly

Im stuck here:

```
function onOpen(){

var ss0 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('MAIN');  
var EndRow = ss0.getLastRow();

for ( var c = 16;c <= 25; c) {
for ( var i = 11;i <= EndRow; i++ ) {


//►PO# VALIDATION►

var range1 = ss0.getRange(i, c);
var rule1 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range1).build();
ss0.getRange(i, 5).setDataValidation(rule1);
}}}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the a sample sheet with sheet data that is similar to your actual spreadsheet so that we can run and replicate your issue more precisely? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Findings:

- Your looping for this part `for ( var c = 16;c <= 25; c) {` has a
  wrong iteration with `c` instead of using `c++`. Thus, this looping
  will never finish running.

### SUGGESTION:

***==UPDATE===***

**You can try this sample script below:**

```
function onOpen(){
  var ss0 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('MAIN');  
  var EndRow = ss0.getLastRow();
  for(row=11; row<=EndRow; row++){
    var data = ss0.getRange("P"+row+":Y"+row).getDisplayValues();
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(data[0]).build();
    ss0.getRange(row,5).setDataValidation(rule);
  }
}
```

### Sample:

> *Result on column 5 or column `E` after the `onOpen()` function finishes running*

[image]

Comment: My goal is to get a validation list on Column 5 (E) from the adjacent range P:Y, each row is a different set of items for the validation . When I tried to code it, the validation list would only have 1 item out of the 10 (p:y).

Comment: example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GhVo5s9M6Rsx_QS9VuR7x8egry0LTjqjazODV_5LEvI/edit?usp=sharing   my goal is to get P11:Y11 range on E11, P12:Y12 range on E12 ..... thanks for taking your time on this!

Comment: @OPSMaheras thanks for your comment. I have updated the script on my answer above. If it answers your question, you may want to click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved & they'll easily see this post on their searches.

Comment: God Bless you man!, works excellently! Thanks again for taking your time on this problem.